# TypeScript - generic being incorrectly inferred as unknown

Tags: typescript

I have the following generic function:

```
export function useClientRequest<T, R extends (...args: any) => AxiosPromise<T>>(
  func: R,
  ...args: Parameters<R>
): [T | undefined, boolean, AxiosError | undefined] {
  // Irrelevant
}
```

Summarily, the function's return contains a value of type T which should be inferred as described above.

I then try to use it as follows:

```
interface Foo {
  // ...
}

function fooGetter(url: string): AxiosPromise<Foo> {
  return Axios.get<Foo>(url);
}

const [data] = useClientRequest(fooGetter, 'url.com');
```

However my IDE reports that `data` is of type `unknown`, because `T` is being inferred as `unknown`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a TypeScript limitation?

Typescript v3.7.2

I know I can specify the type parameters. I'm wondering why they are being inferred incorrectly and if I can somehow change the implementation to help the inferring mechanism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [TypeScript specifications](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3921-type-parameters):

> Type parameters may be referenced in parameter types and return type annotations, but not in type parameter constraints, of the call signature in which they are introduced.

Given your function signature,

```
<T, R extends (...args: any) => AxiosPromise<T>>(
  func: R, ...args: Parameters<R>
): [T | undefined, boolean, AxiosError | undefined]
```

, my interpretation of above statement is, that `T` appears in the type parameter constraint signature `extends (...args: any) => AxiosPromise<T>` of parameter `R` and can therefore not be resolved properly. `unknown` is just the [implicit  default constraint type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown) of generic type parameters.

So these contrived examples would work:

```
declare function fn0<T, U extends T>(fn: (t: T) => U): U
const fn0Res = fn0((arg: { a: string }) => ({ a: "foo", b: 42 }))  // {a: string; b: number;}

declare function fn1<T, F extends (args: string) => number>(fn: F, t: T): T
const fn1Res = fn1((a: string) => 33, 42) // 42
```

In the next two samples the compiler infers `T` to be `unknown`, because `T` is only referenced in the call signature constraint of `U` and not used in function parameter code locations for further compiler hints:

```
declare function fn2<T, U extends (args: T) => number>(fn: U): T
const fn2Res = fn2((arg: number) => 32) // T defaults to unknown

declare function fn3<T, U extends (...args: any) => T>(fn: U): T
const fn3Res = fn3((arg: number) => 42) // T defaults to unknown
```

#### Possible solutions (choose, what fits best)

1.) You can introduce type parameters `T` and `R` just for the function parameters and return type:

```
declare function useClientRequest2<T, R extends any[]>(
    func: (...args: R) => Promise<T>,
    ...args: R
): [T | undefined, boolean, AxiosError | undefined]

const [data] = useClientRequest2(fooGetter, 'url.com'); // data: Foo | undefined
```

2.) Here is an alternative with conditional types (a bit more verbose):

```
declare function useClientRequestAlt<R extends (...args: any) => Promise<any>>(
    func: R,
    ...args: Parameters<R>
): [ResolvedPromise<ReturnType<R>> | undefined, boolean, AxiosError | undefined]

type ResolvedPromise<T extends Promise<any>> = T extends Promise<infer R> ? R : never
const [data2] = useClientRequestAlt(fooGetter, 'url.com'); // const data2: Foo | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggHgSwPYGcCiAnDSNQLxQCuAdgNbFIDuxAUDQscBBgGYCGAxtAGJJJQBvGlBFQA9GIB00qDQC+dACYQOAGzYZoLEh2DJiUFnwDiEYEwwAKQhlUAuKCmAYGAcwCUDgArYAtghQIAB5eJAA+OgkoAGUkVUI9JAMARiUVdU1DHUSDQkCAYVUECEYAJQgAR0IIJwAmIIAVABooUqgIOCZiRRQoNmIQAG0AXTDLYVFtYg4HS2lJDVcUB1L3fDCoHyR-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-UrWt9HEPFW0Qztrh7Z5QkpTQQA)

Comment: What do you mean by *"These not"*? (Respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58781664/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).)

Comment: thanks, this is a very confusing part of typescript, this explains the difference between binding a matching vs consuming a generic.

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer why it does not work. However, I would do something like this:

```js
type UnpackedAxiosPromise<T> = T extends AxiosPromise<infer U> ? U : T; 

function useClientRequest<R extends (...args: any) => any>(
    func: R,
    ...args: Parameters<R>
  ): [UnpackedAxiosPromise<ReturnType<R>> | undefined, boolean, AxiosError | undefined] {
    //irrelevant
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not pass the T to the function, so it does not know what it is. Check the following code:

```
const [data] = useClientRequest<Foo, typeof fooGetter>(fooGetter, 'url.com');
```

If you do it like this, it will know that data can be `Foo | undefined`.

Comment: I understand I can just pass the type parameters, I'm trying to figure out why they are being inferred incorrectly