# Empty optional parameter not inferred as undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why isn't TS inferring the optional parameter in this function as `undefined` when it's omitted from the call?

```js
function fooFunc<T extends number | undefined>(param?: T){
  let x: T extends undefined ? null : T
  x = param ?? null as any 
  return x
}
```

It works as expected if *explicitly* passed `undefined` but not if the argument is just omitted:

```js
const fooResult1:number = fooFunc(3)

const fooResult2:null = fooFunc(undefined) // <-- this works

const fooResult3:null = fooFunc() // <-- this doesn't; it infers null | number, not null
```

Things works as expected if I widen the constraint to include `unknown`, i.e., `<T extends number | undefined | unknown>`, but it's not a great solution as, in real code, `unknown` leads to other problems down the road.

What is going on here and is there a fix/workaround?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?ssl=11&ssc=34&pln=7&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcBi4IB4AqiCmAHlPmACYDOiYIAtgEb4BOiAPouGfsDGPmQD4AFAAcAhkzG0A-AC5EOAJQBvAFCJEAG3xREheXiIlyVTt179E06iE2bEB9XsQBeROMm0r1mncRiqMTAAT0QnJh0QJiRCVQBfVVUIBApdFDgAJXwKWygARlkaBmZXZFQMSCEAZkVE5LBUsszs3IAmQtt7N3SKiCEzHj4yWqSUtNQsnM0oKo6-bvLMIRHQSFgERHoJXtwCYlJKG2KWdgGLMjYOMABrMDgAdzBhDyk5BRUnbV19BT3jQ7OQysNj8jg0hFKLy80h8nX8gRCYQ0ESgURi8TqY02EkmuQKRUYLDcWyYvWqI3qjRJuOm7V8XWxpKWgP4FKx1Ja01m9NKJLJiiAA)

**Update**

It looks like the answer to they "why" part of my question is probably -- it just does.  See [this SO answer by @jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181082/why-are-missing-type-parameters-inferred-as-unknown-in-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1).  So I guess my question is really is there any way around it, or do I just have to go down the path of debugging why `unknown` is giving me problems later on in my code?

**Update 2(revised)**

Here's my issue with `unknown`--if I change the function above to

```js
function fooFunc<T extends number | undefined | unknown>(param?: T){
  let x: T extends undefined ? null : T
  x = param ?? null as any 
  return x
}
```

then it works, in the sense that it will correctly return a `null` type if called without a parameter, i.e, `fooFunc()`.  but the problem is it will also now allow itself to be called with any arbitrary parameter, e.g., `fooFunc("hello")`, which is not the desired behavior.

now, you might say, well that's just because you can always add *extra* arguments in JS, but that's not what's going on here because the same issue happens if the generic is embedded in an object, i.e.,

```
function bazFunc<T extends number | undefined | unknown>(param: {a: number; b?: T}){
  let x: T extends undefined ? null : T
  x = param.b ?? null as any 
  return x
}

bazFunc({a:1, b:"hello"}) // <-- I don't want this
```

[Refined playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?ssl=39&ssc=60&pln=27&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcBi4IB4AqiCmAHlPmACYDOiYIAtgEb4BOiAPouGfsDGPmQD4AFAAcAhkzG0A-AC5EOAJQBvAFCJEAG3xREheXiIlyVTt179E06iE2bEB9XsQBeROMm0r1mncRiqMTAAT0QnJh0QJiRCVQBfVVUIBApdFDgAJXwKWygARlkaBmZXZFQMSCEAZkVE5LBUsszs3IAmQtt7N3SKiCEzHj4yWqSUtNQsnM0oKo6-bvLMIRHQSFgERHoJXtwCYlJKG2KWdgGLMjYOMABrMDgAdzBhDyk5BRUnbV19BT3jQ7OQysNj8jg0hFKLy80h8nX8gRCYQ0ESgURi8TqY02EkmuQKRUYLDcWyYvWqI3qjRJuOm7V8XWxpKWgP4FKx1Ja01m9NKJLJIz5SwARAALfB2OBCxSIAD0MsQWAAtIrEABJRBkBAAcl09yCuigIpgFAAhIlVtB4EgtgAvHaGfYmI6Ey4si6nG53R7PCRSeTKMTyAnMADcmzeODiHw0Xz0Bj%20B1M5HMQNhoIUTghbihADp6N4QfYAv5EeFItE9BjRg1dLaafkOsdeWI7UsA7I8gAaeiyVpRzE17E2%20t0uHEltk9tdzayN396tUlv17ljoeTwN5ee29cdzsz0XizSSqOy%20VKlXqzVgHWIPVgA1Gqj4GCG5gmk1AA)

**Edit 3**

I'm going to mark @kaya3's answer as accepted because I believe it accurately identifies the source of the problem, which is that the conditional type at the start of the function is distributive and so resolves to the *union* of the condition as applied to `number` and `undefined`.  The proposed solution--using overloads--also seems good in many cases.

It did not work in my case because I needed return type inference.  However, overriding the default conditional distributive behavior using `[]` did work.  Thus, an alternate solution for the problem in the question is this, which works as I wanted:

```js
function fooFunc<T extends number | undefined>(param?: T){
  let x: [T] extends [number] ? T: null
  x = param ?? null as any 
  return x
}

const fooResult1:number = fooFunc(3)

const fooResult2:null = fooFunc(undefined)

const fooResult3:null = fooFunc()
```

By using the brackets to *not* distribute the conditional, it now resolves to just the actual value of T in the non-undefined case, which is what I wanted in the particular instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing type parameter is not being inferred as `unknown` here; by hovering over the function call, we can see that the type parameter is inferred as the upper bound `number | undefined`. Therefore the return type `T extends undefined ? null : T`, which is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), resolves as `number | null` because the `number` part maps to `number` and the `undefined` part maps to `null`. So in the third example, the function's return type is `number | null`, which is not assignable to the type `null`, hence the error.

In this case - when you have a generic function with an optional parameter, but it only makes sense to be generic when the parameter *is* present - I think the most sensible workaround is to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). Then you can just directly specify what you want the return type to be when called with no argument, while still letting it be generic when called with an argument.

```
// overload for calling with no argument
function fooFunc(): null;
// overload for calling with one argument
function fooFunc<T extends number | undefined>(param: T): T extends undefined ? null : T;
// actual implementation
function fooFunc<T extends number | undefined>(param?: T) {
  let x: T extends undefined ? null : T
  x = param ?? null as any 
  return x
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcBi4IAoCUAuRMEAG2IG4AoUSWBZVDSAHgBVEBTADynbABMAzoRABbAEbsATogA+icH3bAYYdnwB8WAA4BDSTpEEW+RGy49+QhUpVrEAfmGlERytWjwkKdJlYduvILC4lKy8vw2qhraegb2RjiIAN4UiIjE7FCInEb+FkHWylEOTsQupqnZiAC8iLr6Ig6ORM46QjpgAJ6IlZKZIJJInBQAvhQUEAgCWd4ASuwCJFAAjAREIdK13ozYAMw4lJNg0-Rw84vEUABMayRlWwyYWIW2fAcTUzOo50u7t84PHyQXCUIA)

Comment: Thanks for this idea.  It may be the best answer for the question as posed.  Unfortunately, I can't use overloads in my "real" example because I need return type inference.

Comment: But... the link to distributive conditions was really helpful.  I didn't realize that behavior could be overridden with brackets.  That solved my problem.

Comment: Marking this as accepted, but also see the alternative solution proposed in my edit to the question, i.e., overriding the distributive behavior of the conditional type.

Comment: Yes, if preventing distributivity gives you the desired result then that may be preferable to overloading, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
function fooFunc<T extends number | undefined>(param?: T){
  // let x: T extends undefined ? null : T
  let x = param ?? null as any 
  return x
}
```