# How do I constrain a generic parameter within a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LmyKorYQhlEAA)

I have a `State<S, A>` datatype which models a function that takes an initial state `S` and returns a tuple of an updated state `S` and a result `A`:

```js
type State<S, A> = (s: S) => readonly [S, A];
```

And a type to map the results from a tuple of states:

```js
type MapResults<T extends State<any, any>[]> =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends State<any, infer A> ? A : never };
```

I would like to have a function `zipAll` which takes a tuple of States and returns a State that
resolves with a tuple of values, where:

1. The state parameters `S` are fixed to the same type across all input values.
2. The result type `A` can be polymorphic.

However, TypeScript cannot successfully constrain `S` while allowing `A` to be polymorphic within a single function signature:

```js
declare function zipAll<S, T extends State<S, any>[]>(...states: T): State<S, MapResults<T>>

declare const s0: State<number, string>;
declare const s1: State<number, boolean>;
declare const sBad: State<string, symbol>;

// Error: type `unknown` is not assignable to type `number`.
const notWorking = zipAll(s0, s1, sBad);
```

The workarounds seem to consist of

1. Explicit function overloads for `zipAll`.
2. A "dummy" function that takes an explicit `S` parameter, then returns the actual `zipAll` function which accepts the state arguments with `S` now fixed to the specified type (it would be invoked something like `zipAll<number>()(s0, s1, s2);`).
3. Explicitly pass type parameters to `zipAll` which is going to get verbose very quickly (e.g. `zipAll<number, [State<number, string>, State<number, boolean>]>(s0, s1)`).

Is there a cleaner approach for this in a single function, or have I hit a wall here?

Comment: Seems like this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779360/typescript-generic-being-incorrectly-inferred-as-unknown

Comment: Yep, I think you hit the nail on the head there. It looks like the TS spec is an archived artifact and no longer updated now as well which is a little bizarre.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of generic which is not binded with function argument ? I mean `A` in `type State<S, A> = (s: S) => readonly [S, A];`.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean re-writing the type to be `type State<S> = (s: S) => readonly [S, any]`? That would mean that we couldn't infer the value in the `A` position anymore.