# Typescript generic inference in function

Tags: typescript, generics, zod

Generic inference is an awesome feature of Typescript. There are some times, however, usually when things get more complex, where types are not inferred as I would expect.

For example, I would like the 'options' field to be typed according to 'validationSchema'.

```
import { z } from "zod";

const addInput = <
    TNewFieldName extends string,
    TUnionOptions extends z.ZodUnionOptions,
    TUnionSchema extends z.ZodUnion<TUnionOptions>,
    TNewFieldInput extends
      | {
          type: "select";
          label: string;
          validationSchema: TUnionSchema;
          options: { name: string; value: z.infer<TUnionSchema> }[];
        }
  >(name: TNewFieldName, input: TNewFieldInput) => {
    return { name, input };
  }

const currencyUnionSchema = z.union([z.literal("USD"), z.literal("AUD")]);
// want 'value' field in 'options' to be typed as 'Currency'
type Currency = z.infer<typeof currencyUnionSchema>; 

const result = addInput("someName", {
  type: "select",
  label: "Currency",
  validationSchema: currencyUnionSchema,
  options: [{
    name: "America",
    // @ts-expect-error
    value: "US"
  },
  {
    name: "Australia",
    // @ts-expect-error
    value: "AU"
  }]
})
```

Would anyone be able to provide some insight into why 'options' is not typed from 'validationSchema', and how this goal may be achieved? Thanks

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-H8-1nQCcCgEDdgBO97Eg0Q0HhCg0CpCggA)

After looking at [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779360/typescript-generic-being-incorrectly-inferred-as-unknown), I managed to get the inference for 'options' to work, but now the return type is not as specific as it could be. I'm not sure how to achieve both inference of 'value' and the specific return type.

```
import { z } from "zod";

const addInput = <
  TNewFieldName extends string,
  TUnionOptions extends z.ZodUnionOptions,
>(name: TNewFieldName, input: {
  type: "select";
  label: string;
  validationSchema: z.ZodUnion<TUnionOptions>;
  options: {
    name: string;
    value: z.infer<z.ZodUnion<TUnionOptions>>;
  }[];
} | {
  type: "text",
  label: string;
  validationSchema: z.ZodString
}) => {
  return { name, input };
}
const currencyUnionSchema = z.union([z.literal("USD"), z.literal("AUD")]);
const result = addInput("someName", {
  type: "select",
  label: "Currency",
  validationSchema: currencyUnionSchema,
  options: [{
    name: "America",
    // @ts-expect-error
    value: "US"
  },
  {
    name: "Australia",
    // @ts-expect-error
    value: "AU"
  }]
})

result.input.type // should know type is "select" but is "select" | "text"
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcBEyEAJvgNwBQFAxhAHYDO8AhscQJJ1gCu8AvHAA8FOHAAqAOQCmAdwBiwKQBtiE5iClwpADxhS6xBnCZRgdAOYAaEeICqdYPQDyYGI8Zbd+wygB0ALRJ7dxc3egZrAD4ACjp1KQAucWl5RRU1DUs4Mx4YJIQbGABPMESCBmUpahhyGyVmACNlJJMzc0pRADdmJWBiZjC6AGVqAAspEGYk5ACgh3pBMWDnV3cGSI64CFXw-JtROI0WmFMLTa6e7jKZs0wpKEEZwOJlukXX0LXIjZs0AG0ALqUDAAH0QhRKZXwel0+GsonqTSUx1O7Rs3V6-UGI3Gk2ms2IQxObQoaAAlHA+JFwaIoFIYNwoHREHBDlIsjleOhgTRwvBqIy6XRqEVXjiJsxKX5uPM6NE-jNenooD1ovhbEMACL4MlZRXAZWq-AAQVs2rJALJlFojHgdIY3CU-DgrA4XF4aoYuCkGSkcJpcGKpSS+AqSiqNXhcERzQIAGFBfoRXD0T0+gN3OK8XABVAhSKxWMJVHtoMGEk-gVRAd4iHjRpTNRmCnq3AAPRtuAAARgDAAtDpStUB3noPs4BiriGNfhflGq9W2XXuCY082o6IO93ewPtEOYCOcFBx5OoabZ6I0ADSWSqPbHTBfJzH0HNFuGKMII7iHAANZ0CAZEDSFsiMUNKmqfA4AaLlgDAsMIygsFoR0GogA)

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

In this situation, the problem is that union type can't narrowed if it is outside of the generic declaration between the `<>`.

#### The solution

The solution is to move the union type inside the generic declaration like so:

```js
...
const addInput = <
  TNewFieldName extends string,
  TUnionOptions extends z.ZodUnionOptions,
  TInput extends {
    type: "select";
    label: string;
    validationSchema: z.ZodUnion<TUnionOptions>;
    options: {
      name: string;
      value: z.infer<z.ZodUnion<TUnionOptions>>;
    }[];
  } | {
    type: "text",
    label: string;
    validationSchema: z.ZodString
  }
>(name: TNewFieldName, input: TInput) => {
  return { name, input };
}
...
result.input.type // "select"
```